# Tree Search algorithm (remove front node from the fringe/queue – goal test – expand)

Tags: algorithm, search, tree, artificial-intelligence

1. How many nodes are visited (chosen from the queue) in the worst case using Breadth-First search, when the solution is at depth d, and the branching factor is b, and the depth of the maximum branch is m?
    Give a formula.
2. How many nodes are generated (added to the queue as a result of expanding the parent) in the worst case using Breadth-First search, when the solution is at depth d, and the branching factor is b, and the depth of the maximum branch is m?
     Give a formula.
3. What is the minimum possible size of the queue using Depth-First search, when the solution is at depth d, and the branching factor is b, and the depth of the maximum branch is m?  Explain your answer on a small search tree.

Comment: Please show an attempt at solving the problem yourself. [so] isn't here to do your homework for you, although we'd happily help with your attempt at doing it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. 1 + b + b<sup>2</sup> + ... + b<sup>d</sup> that is *O(b<sup>d</sup>)*
2. 1 + b + b<sup>2</sup> + ... + b<sup>d+1</sup> - b that is *O(b<sup>d+1</sup>)*
3. b * m

Note: fringe in the DFS is stack not queue (or you may call it a LIFO queue).

1, 2 : look at the following figure as an example with b = 3 in which I've shown the goal state by a red circle.

[image]

For this tree all the nodes in the purple box get visited while all of these nodes + nodes in the orange box get added to the fringe.

[image]

3 : In the following figure all the nodes inside the circuit (really poor designed ;D ) get added to the fringe.

[image]

Comment: I was unable yesterday, it said your reputation is not enough to upvote. Now it is. I upvoted! Thank you :)